# Inject current request into service controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

How to inject current request into service controller?

What type should I put in controller?

```
public class RemoteFileServerService : IFileServerService
{

    private readonly HttpContext?????;


    public RemoteFileServerService(??????)
    {

    }
}
```

And how registration should look like?

```
Container.RegisterType<IFileServerService, RemoteFileServerService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: you could explicitly pass it in a method call from within a controller

Comment: But it is usually advised not to tightly couple to HttpContext

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain/show what it is you are actually trying to achieve that would required the injection of the current request? Maybe an alternative can be found.